# Alternatives to using jinja2 delimiters when referencing loop item

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

Novice Ansible user here. So I am trying to automate password changes, and added a conditional to the loop in the play so that the password is only changed when the user exists on the system.

I had the playbook retrieve the list of all the users and then use that with the `when` statement before running the loop.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - /etc/ansible/userlist.yaml

  tasks:
    - name: definepass
      ansible.builtin.shell: tail -1 passlist.yaml
      register: newpassword

    - name: get data
      shell: "getent passwd | cut -d: -f1"
      register: allusers

    - name: change password
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        update_password: always
        password: "{{ 'newpassword'|password_hash('sha256') }}"
      loop: "{{ uservar }}"
      when: '"item" in allusers'
```

```
- uservar:
    - 'testuser' # real user on system
    - 'testuser2' # also a real user on system
    - 'fakeuser' # fake username, does not yet exist on system
- user: 'testuser'
```

(For reference, when I do `getent passwd | cut -d: -f1` in a normal shell window, I get exactly what I should: a long list of usernames with the ones I want inside.)

It seems that the system doesn't understand the condition because it skips all of the users.

```
TASK [definepass] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [get data] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [change password] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=testuser) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=testuser2) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=fakeuser) 

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

(What the new password was supposed to be changed to doesn't work.)

Apologies if the fix is simple, but I'm not sure how best to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**The condition skips all of the users.**"*

A: The standard output from the command is stored in the attribute *stdout* of the registered dictionary *allusers*. In your case, the attribute *stdout_lines* is even more useful. Take a look at the variable

```yaml
    - name: get data
      shell: "getent passwd | cut -d: -f1"
      register: allusers
    - debug:
        var: allusers
```

But, in this case, you should use the Ansible module [*getent*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html#ansible-builtin-getent-a-wrapper-to-the-unix-getent-utility) instead of the module *shell*. The data will be automatically stored in the variable *getent_passwd*, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: get data
      getent:
        database: passed
    - debug:
        var: getent_passwd
```

Then, you can use the data in the condition

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} exists on the system."
      loop: "{{ uservar }}"
      when: item in getent_passwd
      vars:
        uservar:
          - 'testuser'  # real user on system
          - 'testuser2' # also a real user on system
          - 'fakeuser'  # fake username, does not yet exist on system
          - admin
```

gives for example

```yaml
skipping: [localhost] => (item=testuser) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=testuser2) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=fakeuser) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=admin) => 
  msg: admin exists on the system.
```

You might wonder how does the condition work. *getent_passwd* is a dictionary and the test [in](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-tests.in) requires a list (a sequence in the terms of Jinja). The dictionary is transformed to the list of its keys when used as a list.

---

When you keep the registered output of the command the correct form of the condition is

```yaml
      when: item in allusers.stdout_lines
```